# Deploy c++ libraries to Artifactory with Jenkins

Tags: c++, maven, jenkins, dll, artifactory

I am having a problem where I am trying to deploy non-Java artifacts (C++ built DLL) to Artifactory for inclusion in a Java application install.

I am using Jenkins and Gradle with the 'cpp' and 'maven' plugin to build the C++ libraries for the project and create the `pom.xml`.

I can't seem to get the DLL artifacts to deploy. I am using Artifactory OSS
5.9.1.

EDIT:
I am trying to use the Jenkins Artifactory plugin
Below is the Artifactory settings we use for our Java projects and it works. Not sure what I should change for grabbing the built DLL

[Screenshot of Jenkins Artifactory Plugin *More* settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPvWl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jenkins-Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in).
With it you can (Choose one of):

1. Build and upload files with [Maven](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlug-in-ConfiguringMaven2andMaven3Builds) or [Pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-GradleBuildswithArtifactory) jobs.
2. Upload the files with [Generic](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in#JenkinsArtifactoryPlug-in-ConfiguringGeneric(Freestyle)Builds) or [Pipeline](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-UploadingandDownloadingFiles) jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin:goal [deploy:deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html):

> Installs the artifact in the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that Artifactory OSS doesn't support c++ but there is Conan.io which is also by JFrog. The paid version of Artifactory includes support for Conan.io Probably going to try use Conan